# How can I change my Zune ID

Tags: zune

Somehow, when I set up my Windows Phone and installed Zune on my computer, my Zune ID got set to PLAYER9006830876. When I rate Windows Apps, that is what I get identified as. Isn't that disgusting!?

I'd like to change it to the handle I usually use, but I can't find where to change my Zune ID.

Is there some way I can change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in a country that hasn't got XBOX live yet (just like it is the case with Croatia where I live). This means you can't change your ZUNE ID yet. Hopefully with Windows (Phone) 8 this will change

Answer (score 0):

From the phone start screen, go into the "Games" tile; Swipe across to the Xbox LIVE panel (to the right of "collection"). If you tap on "profile", and choose "edit", one of the options in the list is to "Change gamertag" which allows you to change how you show up in the reviews in the Marketplace, within the Zune application, as well as on XBOX Live.

Comment: That sounded good, but when I go into my games tile, there is only the "collection" column. I can't swipe right or left. I don't have an Xbox Live account if that makes a difference.

Comment: What country is your primary Windows Live account associated to? It *may* be the case that XBOX Live isn't supported for your id's locale, so you wouldn't be able to change the id in this manner

Comment: My country is Canada